# Как создать таймер во время работы Tkinter в этом же коде. Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

Нужно сделать так:

Работает Tkinter interface и вместе с этим идёт отсчёт 1 секунды. После этого происходит какое-то действие.

Когда пытаюсь так сделать, ничего не происходит.

Код в функции которая вызывается:

```
def autoc():
    while True:
        time.sleep(1)
        click = click + 1
        lbl.configure(text=int(click))
```

Comment: Покажите весь код потому что здесь у вас про таймер не чего нет

Comment: Не поместится он на 233 строчки,  там все просто, юзер нажимает на кнопку и вызывается эта функция, нужно что-бы когда он нажал был бесконечный цикл в котором каждую секунду происходит действие. И что-бы окно tkinter продолжило работать.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Основные задачи для таймера:

1. Сделать отсчёт времени
2. Вывести отсчёт в другой поток(чтобы GUI не зависал)

С первым вы замечательно справились, значит будем реализовывать второй пункт.

### Вот такой код у меня получился

```
from threading import Thread

....

Thread(target = autoc).start() # Используйте для вызова функции в отдельный поток, тогда остальная часть окна не будет виснуть
....

def autoc(): 
    global click 
    while True: 
        print("auto-click + 1") 
        time.sleep(1) 
        click += 1 
        lbl.configure(text=int(click))
```

Comment: В тексте немного ошибся, у меня как раз не работал отсчёт, я нажимал на кнопку и ничего не происходило. Сейчас же зависает окно, но работает отсчёт. Может я когда чуть-чуть исправлял что-то испортил, вот код в итоге встал в код:
```def autoc():
 global click
 
 while True:
  print("auto-click + 1")
  time.sleep(1)
  Thread(target = time.sleep, args = [1,]).start()
  click += 1
  lbl.configure(text=int(click))```

Comment: @kotivas, изменил код. Теперь должно работать.

Answer (score 0):

*Ну вот так*

```
from tkinter import Tk, Label, Button, mainloop
from threading import Thread
import time


class App(Tk):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.label = Label(self, text="")
        self.label.pack()

        button = Button(self, text="запустить бесконечный цикл")
        button.config(command=self.print)
        button.pack()

        self.update_clock()

    def update_clock(self):
        now = time.strftime("%H:%M:%S")
        self.label.configure(text=now)
        self.after(1000, self.update_clock)
    def print(self):
        def thread():
            while True:
                print("Поток безконечный цикл")
                time.sleep(1)
        Thread(target=thread).start()

def main():
    app = App()
    app.mainloop()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```